[tag:countries], really?
I fail to see any reason to have tag countries.
Is everyone fine with deleting it?

I retagged two questions with countries, but this one makes sense with it, so I left it.

Also see: Do tags for specific countries make sense?

I respectfully disagree. In the bitcoin realm especially, setting and origin can paint the Topic at hand equal shades of subversive,  truly disruptive or positively purposeless grey. No one cares about a BTM in Venezuela because they are a little tied up by their shoe strings on cold concrete wrap in mats. 
Take for example a question posted from an Argentinian inquiring about arbitraging the Blue Note V. Official Note Market, then finally converting into or out of BTC. This is a geographically isolated opportunity and with it comes regionally specific regulation and licensing considerations to say the very minimum. I see weight set upon the scale in instances such as these.
Similarly, a poster inquiring about the particular confidence in BTCx leveraging platforms that are central to Shang Hai, or Singapore for instance, again carries with it a distinct geographical flavor.
-YourBloke

The 'countries' tag, was literally 'countries'. If there was a lot of question activity specifically concerned with one country, a tag for that country might make sense, but a tag that just says 'countries' doesn't really distinguish anything. ;)
